# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax... near if

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My phpmyadmin is getting error with every IF statement. error is,

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF @@R
```

My code is like

```
UPDATE ...... WHERE .... AND `id`="123"
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
INSERT INTO ......
```

how to fix this problem?

Comment: Your mixing SQL-server syntax with MySQL that's your problem.. MySQL doesn't support conditional SQL execution except within functions, procedures and triggers

Comment: `@@ROWCOUNT` is for MS SQL

Comment: `SELECT rows_affected();`, then do the "if" in your application language.

Comment: Consider changing to `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`